# How to make Free or Paid App after scanning the Image for first three times in Android

Tags: android

I have an image which after scanning comes all the details of the image. I want to scan the user just three times which is free After that it should be paid. If someone has any solution or idea then please help. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

1. Create a singleton class, e.g. `BillingManager` that will act as your manager responsible for checking on play-store if the user is paid or not. You can add an `isPremiumUser()` method that you should call in your code to check if an user is premium.
2. Use `SharedPreferences` or other persistent storage to keep the count of how many times the user has used the scan functionality.
3. Decide which functionality you want to block for a non-premium user and decide if you will let the user use the app or not, by making the following checks:

`if (preferences.getInt(KEY_USAGE_COUNT, 0) < 3 || BillingManager.instance.isPremiumUser(){
   //let the user pass
}`

Comment: would be better to also link the app to google account so that user can't cheat by delete and reinstall the app to reset `KEY_USAGE_COUNT`

Comment: This was not meant to be a bullet-proof solution, but merely some guidelines of how a premium-limitation should work. Ofcourse that to avoid cheating, more complicated solutions are required.

Answer (score 0):

This will be done by calling **API** and maintain that counter in **PREFERENCE**. 
You must call **API** for this feature, because whenever user clear data your counter will be removed from **PREFERENCE**.

If you want to maintain your premium features then you have to call **API**